# Merge two array values into one array of objects

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have two arrays:

```
choicesArray = [a, b, a, a, b];

powerUpArray = [double, NP, NA, NA, NP];
```

Now i want to merge this two arrays like this and index should be same:

```
answers: [
           {choice: 'a', power:'double'},
           {choice: 'b', power:'NP'},
           {choice: 'a', power:'NA'},
           {choice: 'a', power:'NA'},
           {choice: 'b', power:'NP'}
       ]
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried? On Stack Overflow you are expected to first attempt to solve your problem and then if you still can't you can show your code that you have written and ask what mistakes you have made.

Comment: thanks for your help. From next time i will be carefull @RobKwasowski

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, here's the answer. I have used "map" function of an array.

```
var answer=[];
var choicesArray = ["a", "b", "a", "a", "b"];
var powerUpArray = ["double", "NP", "NA", "NA", "NP"];

choicesArray.map(function(ele, index){ 
    answer.push({"choice": ele, "power":powerUpArray[index]})
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by simple loop.

```js
var choicesArray = ['a', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'b'];
var powerUpArray = ['double', 'NP', 'NA', 'NA', 'NP'];

let answers = [];
for(let i = 0; i < choicesArray.length; i++) {
  answers.push({
    choice: choicesArray[i],
    power: powerUpArray[i]
  });
}

console.log(answers);
```